# Is there a way to find out the image path of a command in CMD?

Tags: java, cmd, command

sometimes when i type a command in CMD, it will throw a error, for example.
[image]

i have so many version of java in my computer.(no all is installed by myself, the directory of some software will contain a minor java.)

i know the main reason of the problem is the incorrect PATH environment, but the PATH environment contain so many directory, (yeah, i can find out the error by excluding them one by one.) but i just to want to know if there is way to find out the image path of the command?

Comment: First of all you should clean up your JREs / JDKs and the registry. Normally _one_ JDK will do, if you need more (perhaps because you need various versions) you should use the _server JRE_. This does not need to be installed: you just unzip it. It even contains a JDK (although it's name announces only a JRE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "tempfilename=%temp%\temp###.###"
(CALL :getpath)>"%tempfilename%"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%tempfilename%") DO (
 IF NOT EXIST "%%~a\." (ECHO "%%~a" IN PATH but missing) ELSE (
  FOR %%b IN (java.exe java.dll) DO IF EXIST "%%~a\%%b" (
   FOR %%c IN ("%%~a\%%b") DO (ECHO %%~c IN PATH dated %%~tc %%~zc bytes)
  )
 )
)
DEL "%tempfilename%" 2>nul
GOTO :EOF

:getpath
ECHO .
ECHO %path:;=&ECHO(%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should find instances of java.exe and java.dll accessible via the `path`.

It lists the path together with `.` into a temporary file, then uses that file as a directory list to search for the target files.

If any are found, it shows the size, date and location of the file found.

If "size" is zero, then the target found is likely to be a symbolic link.